# Error while sending a video with using python-telegram-bot including a thumbnail through python

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

This is the code I have written in using python-telegram-bot

```
from flask import Flask, request
import telegram
bot_token ="12345678:ABCDEEFGHIjksdfsusk"
bot_user_name ="@thenameofmybot"
global TOKEN
TOKEN = bot_token
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
bot.send_video(chat_id='-1234567890',video=open('k 2.mkv','rb'),thumb=open('picture.jpg'), supports_streaming=False, timeout=1000000)
```

How this is a 52 mb file however I have timeout=1000000 , but i am getting the error

```
telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

After couple of seconds , any idea what this could be?

EDIT: The same code worked when I sent a 40 MB video but no thumbnail was coming. then I changed the code to document so that I can send more than 50 Mb this is the code

```
from flask import Flask, request
import telegram
bot_token ="12345678:ABCDEEFGHIjksdfsusk"
bot_user_name ="@thenameofmybot"
global TOKEN
TOKEN = bot_token
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
files = {'file': ('k 2.mkv', open('k 2.mkv', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'})}
bot.send_document(chat_id='-123456789',document=files, thumb=('picture.jpeg'),timeout=1000000)
```

But it throws an error
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

What am i doing wrong over here , and why is no thumbnail showing up ? the thumbnail file size is below 200Kb and as per documentation the size is only 320px

Comment: According to [this docstring](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/80b34811ab7cfb633d703f88d2a06df6e71d3551/telegram/bot.py#L969-L973) the limit is 50MB.  Can you try with a smaller video file.

Comment: It worked when I sent it as 40 mb file but there was no thumbnail showing , so in order to get the larger file we need to send this is as multipart/form file , any idea how to send it as multipart form? also how to bring it with thumbnail